# Error importing pandas through the bash envrionment

Tags: bash, pandas, import

I've attempted to resolve this with answers to similar issues in the forum but was unsuccessful. Any help would be much appreciated as I've been stuck for a while.

I have downloaded Python through the `Anaconda` distribution.

When I attempt to import pandas by running a script (forum.py) in `GITBASH` I get the following error:

```
$ python forum.py
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "forum.py", line 1, in
>   
>       import pandas as pd   File "C:\Users\jimen\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas__init__.py", line
>   42, in 
>       from pandas.core.api import *   File "C:\Users\jimen\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", line
>   10, in 
>       from pandas.core.groupby import Grouper   File "C:\Users\jimen\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py",
>   line 50, in 
>       from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame   File "C:\Users\jimen\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py",
>   line 77, in 
>       from pandas.core.series import Series   File "C:\Users\jimen\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py",
>   line 81, in 
>       import pandas.plotting._core as gfx   File "C:\Users\jimen\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting__init__.py",
>   line 15, in 
>       from pandas.plotting._converter import \   File "C:\Users\jimen\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting_converter.py",
>   line 8, in 
>       import matplotlib.units as units   File "C:\Users\jimen\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib__init__.py",
>   line 1111, in 
>       rcParamsOrig = RcParams(rcParams.copy())   File "C:\Users\jimen\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib__init__.py",
>   line 891, in **getitem**
>       from matplotlib import pyplot as plt   File "C:\Users\jimen\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py",
>   line 32, in 
>       import matplotlib.colorbar   File "C:\Users\jimen\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py",
>   line 28, in 
>       import matplotlib.artist as martist AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'artist'

I'm not sure what to do and how to resolve this so any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: From the last line, you can see that your version of pandas expects your version of matplotlib to have an artist attribute, and it does not. you should check on your versions of these packages and make sure they are compatible.